# Передача данных в выпадающие меню

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Недавно начал изучение react и material-ui. Пример кода взят из компонента `List` material-ui.
[image: Список]

```
class ProjectDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.deleteNote = this.deleteNote.bind(this);
    }

    deleteNote(note) {
        console.log(note)
    }

    render() {
        const iconButtonElement = (
            <IconButton
                touch
                tooltip="more"
                tooltipPosition="bottom-left"
            >
                <MoreVertIcon color={grey400} />
            </IconButton>
        );

        const rightIconMenu = (
            <IconMenu iconButtonElement={iconButtonElement}>
                <MenuItem>Reply</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>Forward</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={this.deleteNote}>Delete</MenuItem>
            </IconMenu>
        );

        return (
            <div>
                <List>
                    <Subheader>Записи</Subheader>
                    {this.props.notes.map((note) =>
                        <ListItem
                            key={note._id}
                            rightIconButton={rightIconMenu}
                            primaryText={note.title}
                            secondaryText={<p>{note.text}</p>}
                            secondaryTextLines={2}
                        />
                    )}
                </List>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

При клике на кнопку `Delete` в выпадающем списке вызывается метод `deleteNote`, но я не пойму как передать `note` в этот метод по которому был сделан клик, чтобы сделать запрос на удаление.

Comment: Что вообще такое `note`? Сейчас у Вас это параметр, который принимают функции `deleteNote` и `map`, а что это вообще должно быть?

Comment: @Илья Функция `map` не принимает параметр `note`, она передает `note` в функцию обратного вызова. `note` - это объект заметки, получаемый из БД и отображаемый в списке.

Comment: В каком виде приходит note из БД? Можете код добавить?

Comment: @Илья Note приходит в виде текста через websocket.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что `note` Вы передаете в компонент через пропсы? 
Если он в виде строки, попробуйте сделать из него массив или объект в `deleteNote`, затем пробежитесь по этому, например, массиву, сравните `item.id` с `key={note._id}` и получите нужный Вам `note.item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно рендерить менюшки в цикле, а не отдельно из константы их брать

```
 class ProjectDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.deleteNote = this.deleteNote.bind(this);
  }

  deleteNote(note) {
    console.log(note)
  }

  render() {
    const iconButtonElement = (
      <IconButton
        touch
        tooltip="more"
        tooltipPosition="bottom-left"
      >
        <MoreVertIcon color={grey400} />
      </IconButton>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <List>
          <Subheader>Записи</Subheader>
          {this.props.notes.map((note) =>
            <ListItem
              key={note._id}
              rightIconButton={
                <IconMenu iconButtonElement={iconButtonElement}>
                  <MenuItem>Reply</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem>Forward</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem onClick={() => 
                       this.deleteNote(note)}>Delete</MenuItem>
                </IconMenu>
              }
              primaryText={note.title}
              secondaryText={<p>{note.text}</p>}
              secondaryTextLines={2}
            />
          )}
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

А еще, если количество элементов меню фиксированно и их не много, можно сделать отдельный компонент и передавать в него note:

```
function Menu(props) {
  const { note } = props;

  return(
    <IconMenu iconButtonElement={iconButtonElement}>
      <MenuItem onClick={() => 
                props.onReplyClick(note.reply)}>Reply</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={() => 
                props.onForwardClick(note.next)}>Forward</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={() => 
                props.onDeleteClick(note.delete)}>Delete</MenuItem>
    </IconMenu>
  )
}
```

Применение:

```
<Menu
  note={note}
  onReplyClick={item => console.log(item)}
  onForwardClick={item => console.log(item)}
  onDeleteClick={item => console.log(item)}
/>
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, я уже понял что меню нужно обязательно выносит в отдельный компонент.